# Groovy, embedded in Java, calling back to Java

Tags: java, groovy, classpath

I know I have to be doing something just brain-dead stupid for this not to work, but I'm in a situation where I want to dynamically load behavior into a running server.  I chose groovy as my tool to do this.  The behavior will need to reference classes on the server's classpath, such as my model objects as well as third party libraries like Freemarker.

I threw together this silly POC to show feasibility.  I can't get the groovy script to resolve the Java classes "ThingyDoodle" and "Fooable", in spite of the fact that I am setting the parent classpath of the GroovyClassPath to be my current.

```
public class GroovyTest
{
    public static void main ( String [ ] argv ) throws Throwable
    {
            // Setting parent classloader!
            // also tried plain old "GroovyTest.class.getClassLoader()" as well
        GroovyClassLoader gcl = new GroovyClassLoader ( Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader() ) ;
        String src =
              "class Arf implements Fooable {
                 public String foo ( ) {
                   return new ThingyDoodle().doStuff('Arf');}}" ;
        Class clazz = gcl.parseClass(src, "AppleSauce.groovy");
        Object aScript = clazz.newInstance();
        Fooable myObject = (Fooable) aScript;
        System.out.println ( myObject.foo() ) ;
    }

    public static interface Fooable { public String foo ( ) ; }

    public static class ThingyDoodle
    {
        public String doStuff ( String input )
        {
            return "Hi Worlds" ;
        }
    }
}
```

What the heck am I doing wrong here?

```
Exception in thread "main" org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
AppleSauce.groovy: 1: unable to resolve class Fooable
 @ line 1, column 1.
   class Arf implements Fooable { public String foo ( ) { return new ThingyDoodle().doStuff('Arf');}}
   ^

AppleSauce.groovy: 1: unable to resolve class ThingyDoodle
 @ line 1, column 63.
   ublic String foo ( ) { return new Thingy
                                     ^
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem in your code is that the **Fooable** interface and **ThingyDoodle** class cannot be found because they're both internal classes and need to be qualified with the containing class name, i.e. **GroovyTest**. I qualified both names in the embedded script (and fixed the quotes around the script) and it ran as expected.

```
import groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader;

public class GroovyTest
{

    public static void main ( String [ ] argv ) throws Throwable
    {
            // Setting parent classloader!
            // also tried plain old "GroovyTest.class.getClassLoader()" as well
        GroovyClassLoader gcl = new GroovyClassLoader ( Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader() ) ;
        String src =
              "class Arf implements GroovyTest.Fooable { " + 
                 "public String foo ( ) { " + 
                   "return new GroovyTest.ThingyDoodle().doStuff('Arf');}}" ;
        Class clazz = gcl.parseClass(src, "AppleSauce.groovy");
        Object aScript = clazz.newInstance();
        Fooable myObject = (Fooable) aScript;
        System.out.println ( myObject.foo() ) ;
    }       
     public static interface Fooable { public String foo ( ) ; }

    public static class ThingyDoodle
    {
        public String doStuff ( String input )
        {
            return "Hi Worlds" ;
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Don't sweat it. I excel at finding fault [bugs] in others, but blind to my own [bugs].... :)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how you're compiling it...  I tried this (using [Gradle](http://gradle.org/) as the build tool) and it works...

./build.gradle

```
apply plugin:'application'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.codehaus.groovy', name: 'groovy', version: '1.8.6'
}

mainClassName = 'org.timyates.GroovyTest'
```

./src/main/java/org/timyates/Fooable.java

```
package org.timyates ;

public interface Fooable {
  public String foo() ;
}
```

./src/main/java/org/timyates/ThingyDoodle.java

```
package org.timyates ;

public class ThingyDoodle {
  public String doStuff( String input ) {
    return String.format( "Hi %s", input ) ;
  }
}
```

./src/main/java/org/timyates/GroovyTest.java

```
package org.timyates ;

import groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader ;

public class GroovyTest {
  public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
    GroovyClassLoader gcl = new GroovyClassLoader( GroovyTest.class.getClassLoader() ) ;
    String src = "import org.timyates.*\n" +
                 "class Arf implements Fooable {\n" +
                 "  public String foo() {\n" +
                 "    new ThingyDoodle().doStuff( 'tim' )\n" +
                 "  }\n" +
                 "}" ;
    Class clazz = gcl.parseClass( src, "AppleSauce.groovy" ) ;
    Fooable myObject = (Fooable)clazz.newInstance() ;
    System.out.println( myObject.foo() ) ;
  }
}
```

Then, when I enter `gradle run` at the command line, I get the output:

```
$ gradle run
:compileJava
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes
:run
Hi tim

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

Comment: I'm compiling it inline, at runtime, within a J2EE server.  If I were to use gradle it would defeat the purpose of this exercise. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Fair enough, glad it got sorted :-)  Putting that sort of info in the question might save time next time ;-)  Good luck with it!