# how to deploy Grails app on G-WAN

Tags: grails, g-wan

Does anybody deployed Grails app on G-WAN? is there any way to make GRAILs be deployable on G-WAN? I searched on internet and read G-WAN documents but there is nothing of use at all.

Answer (score 0):

> any way to make GRAILs deployable on G-WAN?

`Grails` uses the `Groovy` programming language (which is based on `Java`) and G-WAN supports Java.

Therefore, you can just write a G-WAN `Java` script to call `Groovy` G-WAN scripts.

A Java example is given there:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10331748/1079036

If there is enough demand, we can add G-WAN support for native `Groovy` scripts.

Comment: Thanks for answer. But it would be great if we can add support for the Groovy. Groovy is one of best programmer friendly language. I read the documentation of G-WAN but i dint understand how does it work with Java , i mean architecture.

Comment: G-WAN loads the JVM and implements Java calls via the JNI (Java Native Interface) in C. We could add support for Groovy like it was done for Scala (another JVM-based language), but at this time, no registered G-WAN user has requested such a support, and you are the first unregistered G-WAN user to mention Groovy. G-WAN supports 15 programming languages - and the two main virtual machines (the SUN/ORACLE JVM and the Microsoft CLR) - far more than any other server. We can only afford to expand this support when users participate to the effort.